# How do I attach a flat/gable verandah to an existing house?

Tags: outdoor, pergola

I would to build a verandah similar to

[image]
<sub>(source: [hicraft.com.au](http://hicraft.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/IMGP5287-01.jpg))</sub>
.

It will be attached to the fascia at the back of my house. I'm building it using timber frame and zinc aluminium roof sheets. I initially wanted to do a flat verandah but I really like the look of a gable in the middle, similar to the picture. There are two things I'm concerned about though:

1. Since I'm using a timber frame, how would I cover the triangle opening on the gable closest to the house? Would I need to use some form of roof sheet as well, and cap it all around the perimeter of the triangular shape? I'm just really concerned that it will leak underneath into the door area.
2. Would I need a box gutter in between the verandah and the existing house? Or would I just need to lay the roofing sheets below the roof tiles of the existing house, so that any rain runoff will fall on the verandah roof and into its eave guttering.

Comment: What kind of climate are you in? Ever get snow? What kind of roof (and how high, relative to the peak of the new gable) is there already?

Comment: I'm in Australia and the most extreme weather we get is strong winds and heavy rain/hail. Never any snow. The roof on the existing house is tiled and was planning to have it positioned higher than the roof of the verandah so that any runoff will fall onto the verandah roof, without the need for a gutter in between. Although the edge of the existing roof will be at least 50cm lower than the height of the proposed gable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd build out from your existing roof, in line with the peak on the new verandah. (Call this a dormer.) Fill in the gable end of the new dormer on the existing roof (just as in the picture you provided), and you won't have problems with leakage in the door area. (Nor would you need a gutter.) The only faintly tricky part of this is that you'd need to tie the new roof into your existing tiles, but that's what roofers do all the time.
If this isn't clear, ping back and I'll post a picture.

Edit one: a picture, so we're on the same page... (and some massaging of the text above in hopes of clarity).
[image: super-rad rendering]
- red is your existing roof
- green is the wall of the existing house
- blue is the top of the dormer that would be added onto your roof
- yellow is the gable end of the new dormer
- the wireframe is the rest of your new verandah

So, filling in the yellow bit is very straightforward, because you've got structure behind in the new blue dormer (that I've suggested you build). Because you have that new dormer, no rain will end up near your door. (You will need to do a little bit of work making sure there's enough slope to drain water off the flatter bits of the verandah, though.)

Clear as mud? If not, ping back.

Comment: When you say "fill in the gable end of the new structure" as displayed in the picture, I actually don't know how they've done it in the picture, and how exactly they've constructed it to prevent any of the unwanted leakage onto door opening area.

Perhaps if you could please provide the picture that you suggest would help me visualize, that would be fantastic. Thank you :-)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying mate, that is definitely clear as mud, brilliant picture too! Really appreciate the help and I'm definitely going to consider this approach. You've given me hope and some ideas mate, thanks again.